# Zend query update

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want t make a zend update query.

I was looking at [**zend documentation**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html)  but I didn't see any example like the one I want.

The question its if may someone could help me with the query.

I want to make the next query:

```
Update cars set active = 0 
Where id in (SELECT idCar FROM UserCars Where idUser=3)
```

Comment: i Saw the zend documentation but i didnt see any example like that and post it here because someone could help me.
Here its the link i was lookin at
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html

Comment: Sorry for bad translation i'm not very good in English, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to run any complex query. There can be some better ways to do same.

```
$sql = "Update cars set active = 0 
Where id in (SELECT idCar FROM UserCars Where idUser=3)";
$query = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->query($sql, $data);
$query->execute();
```

Try this too

```
$data = array { 'active' = '0' };
$where = "id in (SELECT idCar FROM UserCars Where idUser=3)";
$db->update($data, $where);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps more Zendy way:

```
$idUser = 3;
$sub_select
  = $db->select()
       ->from('UserCars', array('id'))
       ->where('idUser = ?', $idUser);

$updated_rows 
  = $db->update('cars', 
        array('active' => 0),
        "id IN ($sub_select)" 
    );
```